# R Create Custom List

Tags: r, string, paste

```
paste0("a",1:5)
"a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5"
```

I want this output:
"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"

I tried paste0("a",1:5, sep=",") but also paste0("a",1:5, collapse=",") but these did not do it.

Comment: Do you need `toString(paste0("a",1:5))` Or `paste0("a",1:5, collapse = ",")` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Those Did Not Do It, Thank You Though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
paste0('"a', 1:5, '"', collapse = ',')
#[1] "\"a1\",\"a2\",\"a3\",\"a4\",\"a5\""
```

R uses backslashes to print quotes, to see the actual string use `cat`

```
cat(paste0('"a', 1:5, '"', collapse = ','))
#"a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"
```

Comment: And What If I Wish To Store This In VEC? VEC=cat(paste0('"a', 1:5, '"', collapse = ',')) just prints not stores

Comment: You should use `vec <- paste0('"a', 1:5, '"', collapse = ',')`. It is storing what you are seeing with `cat` but when you print it, this is how R displays string with quotes.

Comment: This Is OutPut: "\"a1\",\"a2\",\"a3\",\"a4\",\"a5\"" when stored using this code. Is this ok or will it look for the \

Comment: Yes, this is how it will look when the string has quotes (`""`).

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `str_c` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_c('"a', 1:5, '"', collapse=",")
#[1] "\"a1\",\"a2\",\"a3\",\"a4\",\"a5\""
```

---

Or with `base R` with `dQuote` and `paste`

```
dQuote(paste0('a', 1:5), q = FALSE)
```